# R .Fortran return reshaped array?

Tags: arrays, r, fortran

I am exploring the implementation of some Fortran code into R.  As a simple example, I wanted to create a simple Fortran file to transpose an R matrix.  I know that `.Fortran` only will return arguments submitted to it.  With that in mind, I would like to avoid sending a blank matrix to house the new values as I hope to extend some Fortran to some very large matrices which would likely result in increased overhead in R (please correct me if I'm wrong here).  Therefore, I am trying to transpose the submitted matrix and return it as the same argument.  I have succeeded in getting the desired output within the Fortran code but cannot get it to return properly in R.  You will see below that the print statement returns the appropriately shape array but the array returned as 'A' is still incorrect.  I initially suspected something with allocating arrays but R keeps crashing when I try to implement.  Any insight would be appreciated.

test.f90

```
subroutine trans(A,n,m)
implicit none

integer, intent(in) :: n,m
double precision, intent(inout) :: A(n,m)

! declare local array to hold transpose
double precision :: B(m,n)

! do the transpose
B = transpose(A)

! try to reshape and reassign A
A = reshape(A, shape(B))
print*,A

end
```

Compile for R use

```
R CMD SHLIB test.f90
```

R code

```
# or trans.so if on unix
dyn.load("test.dll")

# create simple matrix
set.seed(123)
a <- matrix(rnorm(15), 3, 5)
> a
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.5604756 0.07050839  0.4609162 -0.4456620  0.4007715
[2,] -0.2301775 0.12928774 -1.2650612  1.2240818  0.1106827
[3,]  1.5587083 1.71506499 -0.6868529  0.3598138 -0.5558411

# call fortran function
.Fortran("trans", a, as.integer(3), as.integer(5))

#output
>.Fortran("trans", a, as.integer(3), as.integer(5))
 -0.56047565 -0.2301775  1.5587083
  0.07050839  0.1292877  1.7150650
  0.46091621 -1.2650612 -0.6868529
 -0.44566197  1.2240818  0.3598138
  0.40077145  0.1106827 -0.5558411

[[1]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] -0.5604756 0.07050839  0.4609162 -0.4456620  0.4007715
[2,] -0.2301775 0.12928774 -1.2650612  1.2240818  0.1106827
[3,]  1.5587083 1.71506499 -0.6868529  0.3598138 -0.5558411

[[2]]
[1] 3

[[3]]
[1] 5
```

Comment: The transpose looks correct to me. What were you expecting?

Comment: @HongOoi, yes the transpose is correct but that is only printed, I have no current means of capturing it.

Answer (score 1):

`.Fortran` returns its output in a list, whose components are the same as its arguments. So you want to do

```
a <- .Fortran("trans", a, 3L, 5L)[[1]]
```

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been clear enough, I edited the code above to show that the argument returned is the same as the original matrix.  The print statement in the fortran allows me to see that the transpose has worked appropriately.  I want the printed output to replace the original `a` matrix.

Comment: Just to confirm, there is no way to have the dimensions of the submitted matrix `a` be different after being processed by the Fortran?  I am not strictly interested in capturing the 'printing' but to get what was printed to be returned as the `.Fortran("trans",...)[[1]]`